# jQuery Masonry create a “clear:both” style break in layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm creating a vertical timeline (trying with jQuery Masonry but happy for other suggestions) but instead of just having them displayed flowing down the timeline, every so often I want to have a small gap (to insert the year), and then start the items flow again. You can use margin-top to give space between the items, but that is only on one side, i.e. doesnt affect the other side of the timeline (see box 5 in the fiddle).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hobailey/P3Ekb/) (Is too much code to include here)

`$('#timelineContainerOuter').masonry({itemSelector : '.item',});`
etc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're after [jquery Isotope Spine Align](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/spine-align.html) by the same plugin author, if I understand your layout concept.